# Settings schema 'gnome.org.desktop.a11y.magnifier' does not contain a key named 'invert-lightness' Error when using GNOME

Tags: gnome

I have just installed the gnome-shell on my ubuntu 12.04.
When I login I get this error:

```
GLib-GIO-ERROR: **: Settings schema 'gnome.org.desktop.a11y.magnifier'
does not contain a key named 'invert-lightness'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Because of this error the gnome-shell doesn't start at all!

When I installed it I followed these instructions: http://www.filiwiese.com/installing-gnome-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. What solved the problem was to reinstall the gsettings schemas:

```
sudo apt-get install gsettings-desktop-schemas
```

Comment: My specific problem was "'org.gnome.desktop.privacy' does not contain a key named 'usb-protection'". This worked for me on Archlinux 7 years, 9 months, 10 days after your answer. Re-installed with `sudo pacman -S gsettings-desktop-schemas` and rebooted.

Comment: @PaulParker Thank you for linking to arch linux, you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it manually:

```
gsettings set gnome.org.desktop.a11y.magnifier invert-lightness false
```

And report back for further errors.