# Gnome Shell refuses to load on 12.04

Tags: gnome, gui, autostart

Gnome Shell isn't loading and I can't figure out why. According to this snapshot of `.xsession-errors`, it seems to(?) have something to do with magnifier:

```
(gnome-shell:2886): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier' does not contain a key named 'invert-lightness'
gnome-session[2262]: WARNING: Application 'gnome-shell.desktop' killed by signal 5
gnome-session[2262]: WARNING: App 'gnome-shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
gnome-session[2262]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

Now, `org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier` most definitely *does* contain `invert-lightness` because I just added it in both `dconf-editor` and `gconf-editor` as `false`, [as suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150991/settings-schema-gnome-org-desktop-a11y-magnifier-does-not-contain-a-key-named). After a reboot, the message still appears.

So, what does this error mean? Is adding `invert-lightness` not what it's asking for?

[image: Programs are still usable but there's no window manager at all]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out it wasn't the settings in `dconf-editor` it was looking for specifically, but somehow the schema had gotten out of sync.

**First** try reinstalling the package `gsettings-desktop-schemas`; it didn't work in my case:

**If that doesn't work**, and this is a bit of a hack, but using the information from [the Gnome Shell docs](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Magnification), I recreated the schema entries and compiled them. Gnome Shell lives!

**Add missing values**

Using (after backing up the file)

> `gksudo gedit /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier.gschema.xml`

add the following somewhere in the middle:

```
<key type="b" name="invert-lightness">
  <default>false</default>
  <summary>Invert lightness</summary>
  <description>(none)</description>
</key>
<key type="d" name="brightness-red">
  <default>0</default>
  <range min="-1.0" max="1.0"/>
  <summary>Brightness (red)</summary>
  <description>Values range between -1.0 to 1.0, where zero indicates no change in brightness, negative values indicate a decrease in brightness and positive values, an increase.</description>
</key>
<key type="d" name="brightness-green">
  <default>0</default>
  <range min="-1.0" max="1.0"/>
  <summary>Brightness (green)</summary>
  <description>Values range between -1.0 to 1.0, where zero indicates no change in brightness, negative values indicate a decrease in brightness and positive values, an increase.</description>
</key>
<key type="d" name="brightness-blue">
  <default>0</default>
  <range min="-1.0" max="1.0"/>
  <summary>Brightness (blue)</summary>
  <description>Values range between -1.0 to 1.0, where zero indicates no change in brightness, negative values indicate a decrease in brightness and positive values, an increase.</description>
</key>
<key type="d" name="contrast-red">
  <default>0</default>
  <range min="-1.0" max="1.0"/>
  <summary>Contrast (red)</summary>
  <description>(none)</description>
</key>
<key type="d" name="contrast-green">
  <default>0</default>
  <range min="-1.0" max="1.0"/>
  <summary>Contrast (green)</summary>
  <description>(none)</description>
</key>
<key type="d" name="contrast-blue">
  <default>0</default>
  <range min="-1.0" max="1.0"/>
  <summary>Contrast (blue)</summary>
  <description>(none)</description>
</key>
```

**Recompile the Schema**

`sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`

Once you next logout, select "GNOME" at log in and it should be fixed.

*(Note: If the above xml data I recreated could be updated at some point from a working installation, I think that would be even better.)*